# Calculate Per Consumer Cost of Azure Event Hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I have 1 event hub with 3-4 consumers. How can I calculate the cost per consumer?
means how much data consumed by which consumer? How can I calculate?

Comment: Normally each consumer gets the same data. Why do you think they are different?

Comment: @Mikhai l need to calculate **the cost**. How much they have consumed. not what they have consumed.

Comment: Cost is per provisioned throughput, extra consumer doesn't cost extra if you stay within provisioned capacity.

Comment: @Mikhail I am publishing data and I want to charge my clients who are receiving that data. Can I do that? Suppose 1 client consumes all the data and another didn't read a byte, How can I charge them? same?

Comment: @Mikhail Is there any way to do that? or should I publish same data to diff event hub for diff consumers/ clients?

Comment: You are talking about consumers but can we safely assume you did set up multiple consumer groups, one for each customer/consumer? Might be a silly question but we need to be sure as there is a big difference between a consumer and a consumer group.

Comment: @PeterBons Yes I am talking about consumer groups